# Calculating the radius of convergence for $\sum _{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\left(\sqrt{ n^2+n}-\sqrt{n^2+1}\right)^n}{n^2}z^n$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

> Calculate the radius of convergence for
>   $$\sum _{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\left(\sqrt{ n^2+n}-\sqrt{n^2+1}\right)^n}{n^2}z^n.$$

Do I have to do a index shift so the sum starts at $0$? I tried it like here (without index shift) [Finding the_radius of convergence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radius_of_convergence#Finding_the_radius_of_convergence), 
and my solution for the denominator is $+\infty$ so in the end my radius of convergence should be $0$.

Is that correct?  Thanks!

Comment: why are you asking the same question twice?https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2603341/finding-radius-of-convergence-sum-n-02-1nnzn/2603518#2603518

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you are not correct. In order to find the radius of convergence you are supposed to evaluate the reciprocal of the limit of $|a_n|^{1/n}$ (the so-called [root-test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_test)) where $a_n$ is the coefficient of $z^n$. Now note that as $n\to+\infty$,
$$\sqrt{ n^2+n}-\sqrt{n^2+1}=\frac{(n^2+n)-(n^2+1)}{\sqrt{ n^2+n}+\sqrt{n^2+1}}=\frac{1-\frac{1}{n}}{\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{n}}+\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{n^2}}}\to \frac{1}{2}.$$
Can you take it from here and find the correct radius of convergence?

Comment: Ok I understood it now. But why can I simply drop the $| \  |$ of $|a_n|$?

Comment: @michael3231  Because $\sqrt{ n^2+n}\geq \sqrt{n^2+1}$ and therefore $|a_n|=a_n$.

Answer (score 0):

Note that $$\Big(\frac{1}{n^2}(\sqrt{ n^2+n}-\sqrt{n^2+1})^n\Big)^{1/n}=\frac{\sqrt{ n^2+n}-\sqrt{n^2+1}}{(n^{1/n})^2}$$
Now $\lim_{n\to\infty}n^{1/n}=1$ and $\lim_{n\to\infty}(\sqrt{ n^2+n}-\sqrt{n^2+1})=\frac12$. Hence $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\Big(\frac{1}{n^2}(\sqrt{ n^2+n}-\sqrt{n^2+1})^n\Big)^{1/n}=\frac12$$
You need to use the [Root Test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_test#Test) now.